# OSM OpenLayers Rotate line

Tags: rotation, line, openlayers, openstreetmap

Having this code where I draw a line between two points, I want to rotate the line. Please, I don´t want to change the points coordinates, just rotate the line.
Note: Got the API from openlayers.org

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OSM line with direction</title>
        <style type="text/css">         
            html, body, #basicMap { 
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script>
            var toProjection;
            var fromProjection;
            var map;

            function init() {

                map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");               
                var zoom            = 7;             
                fromProjection      = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
                toProjection        = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                var positionInicial = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);                             
                var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(null,null,{maxZoomLevel: 17, numZoomLevels: 17});
                map.addLayer(mapnik);   

                var mappoints = new Array(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()), new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(1, 1).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));

                var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer"); 
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));      
                var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(mappoints);
                var style = { 
                  strokeColor: '#0000ff', 
                  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                  strokeWidth: 5
                };
                var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
                lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
                map.addLayer(lineLayer);  


               //HERE COMES THE CODE TO ROTATE THE LINE
               //....

                map.setCenter(positionInicial, zoom);

            }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <div id="basicMap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [`rotate()` function of `OpenLayers.Geometry.Point`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.rotate)? It seems sufficient to rotate both points around the center of an imaginary line between them, and create the real line afterwards.

Comment: Yes I tried but throws me an error (nothing is shown) when i use that function. May be I'm using it wrong, thats why I'm asking for help. If you can show me a rotation example on my code it would be useful. THX.
PD: I tried lineFeature.geometry.rotate(30, new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0));